# Windows 10 keeps enabling the SysMain service

Tags: windows-10, services, superfetch

### EDIT: I answered to myself. Read it below this post.

I bought a new laptop, [MSI GV62 7RC](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/GV62-7RC/Specification), and installed the latest Win 10 1909 from scratch and fully updated it.

I right click This Computer and go to Computer Management -> Services where I disable the automatic start of the SysMain service (it's responsible for preloading frequently launched applications' data and was formerly known as Superfetch). However, it is re-enabled every few reboots.

Never before have I encoutered such behaviour. On other PCs, when I disable the SysMain service, it stays that way.

How do I keep it disabled?

Comment: What version are the other machines running?

Comment: The same Win 10 1909, fully updated.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I know what happened.

It turns out that the SysMain service is needed for the Windows 10 Memory Compression feature to work. I didn't know that. So when I disable the SysMain service (it disables the Memory Compression too), and then go to PowerShell to enable the Memory Compression (enable-mmagent -memorycompression), it enables SysMain, too.